# Aligning grandchild elements with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am learning flexbox and still not sure I fully understand how all the parts fit together. I would like to vertically align these columns so that the gray boxes line up with each other: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPZQZq (I updated the Codepen HTML/CSS to better reflect the challenge with my responsive layout.)

Some additional context: this is for a site that is responsive, so the `width: 800px` may be a bit misleading. And the gray bars can't be replaced by borders, they're meant to be stand-ins for actual content.

Code:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#container {
  width: 800px;
  font: 14px/22px "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.item .blob {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title TK</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>A longer title TK TK TK</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>A title that nobody could have possibly accounted for</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the layout that you want is a <table>. I know that a lot of people say that you shouldn't use it . But there are cases where it **is** the non javascript solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to control the height of `.item h1`. You can do it by either:

```
.item h1 {
   min-height: 90px;
   max-height: 90px;
}
```

or, the flexbox way:

```
.item h1 {
   flex-basis: 90px;
   flex-shrink: 0; /* if you don't want it to shrink */
   flex-grow: 0; /* if you don't want it to grow */
}
```

Comment: Ah, I liked your earlier solution better, with the `min-height` and `max-height`.

Comment: I added it back. Why do you prefer the box-model solution of controlling height and not the flexbox one?

Comment: Yeah, I think in the end I'm going to use a non-flexbox solution. Controlling the height of the `<h1>` seems like the best solution. It's slightly hacky since I will need to set a few breakpoints specific to widths where the titles word wrap.

Comment: The two blocks of code do exactly the same (now that I added `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to the flexbox one). So you will only need to change `flex-basis` at different screen widths.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can't align or equalise items that **do not share a common parent**...so there is no native flexbox method here.

The header would need to be the same height in each column.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  font: 14px/22px"helvetica neue", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.item h1 {
  height: 120px;
}
.item .blob {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title TK</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>A longer title TK TK TK</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>A title that nobody could have possibly accounted for</h1>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence of your answer. I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/no73st0h/) for you.

Comment: I have no idea what your fiddle is attempting to demonstrate but if you think you can solve the OP's issue with it...please provide your own answer. Flexbox cannot make elements with different parents the same height,

Comment: As long as the parents are same height (or width for rows) and the children have the same `flex-basis`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`, the children from different parents will always be aligned. In `height` if the parents are columns and in `width` if parents are rows.

Comment: Which is what we answered above...that's just making all the child elements the same height anyway...it's nothing to do with flexbox.

Comment: You're right. We're technically disabling `flexbox`. So it acts like a `grid`.